# Tracking Dataframe changes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to track the basic CRUD operations performed on a Pandas' Dataframe?

Is so how?  If not, does anyone know of a recommended way to extend the dataframe to do so?

Thank you

Comment: What counts as a basic change? You need to specify this explicitly. Also, why wouldn't you as the programmer know exactly when you are changing your dataframe? I think more context would be helpful.

Comment: you could use postgreSQL with pandas. `"A psycopg2 wrapper using pandas DataFrame to perform CRUD operations with PostgreSQL"` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypostgres/0.6.1

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga when you are adding, deleting and removing data on large datasets, it would be nice to have a generic change tracker.  I was pretty explicit on what I am trying to track: CRUD operations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete

Comment: @MaxPower would this give me the ability to tell me what changed within the dataframe?  Like a delta file?

Comment: Right, I understand what CRUD means, but a `pandas.DataFrame` is not a database. Usually, you the programmer are directly manipulating it. Is your dataframe part of some service that lives in-memory and can be modified dynamically outside of your control? Because then it sounds like you *should* be using a database. There is likely no simple way, since there are so many methods that can change a dataframe. But no, there is no built-in change tracker for pandas dataframes, as far as I am aware.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the data comes from a web service, and the web service requires explicit entries for updates, adds and deletes.  To help users, I created a class that pulls data from the web service to a dataframe, now I need a way to track the changes the user does before they push their changes back to the service.